# Relationship Modelling Assistance - Normalisation

Tags: normalization, erd

I need to create an ER diagram and a relational model for a hospital. I have kept it simple to 3 entities. Please can someone have a look and tell me if I have normalised this correctly?

I am not sure it there should be a *:* relationship between the trust and patients? Does a person assume that the first entity is a single unit, in this case **a** hospital has x relationships to....

Diagram 2: 
[ER Diagram & Relational Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkV6k.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your normalization isn't correct.  First of all, you don't list functional dependencies.  Without that, any attempt to normalize is just guesswork.

Now, I can make a reasonable guess, but even with that you have some problems.  The `Hires` and `Cares for` relations aren't reflected in your 1NF/2NF/3NF tables.  In your 2NF, you introduce a `Shift` relation that was presumably derived from `Doctor` in 1NF, but `Patient_ID` wasn't present in the latter, unless that's actually what the Shift column was for, but renaming fields isn't part of normalization.  Also, what happened to `Hospital` in 2NF?  It reappears in 3NF but with a `Location` attribute that was derived from where?  Also, you're not indicating a primary key for `Shift`, is it correct to assume the combination of all 4 fields constitute a candidate key?  It's good practice to be explicit about your keys.

> Can an entity be without attributes?

Your `Hospital` relation does have an attribute - `Hospital_ID`, which represents an identity relation.  Remember an attribute is a binary relation, and `Hospital_ID -> Hospital_ID` qualifies.

> I am not sure it there should be a : relationship between the trust and patients?

What is `the trust`?  It isn't indicated in your diagram at all.

> Does a person assume that the first entity is a single unit, in this case a hospital has x relationships to....

Many-to-many relationships are decomposed into two or more one-to-many relationships, and in reading the cardinality indicators we tend to put the singular entity first, but this isn't a rule or a safe assumption.  Be explicit about cardinalities.

Comment: Hi Reaanb, Thank you very much for taking the time to look over this. I have worked through it and updated the diagrams and also I have included a relational schema (as I now understand this - I think). Can you let me know your thoughts? Not sure where to upload more docs?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add more links. Can I PM you?

Comment: I still don't see your functional dependenices and how you derived the Shift table.  Instead of uploading more documents, you can update your question.  Sorry, I won't respond to PMs.  I post publicly to teach and learn.

Comment: Hi Reenb, I have re-attached the screen shots to include the functional dependency. I created The Shift table in order to break up the many-to-many relationship between Hospital and Doctor. This was to normalize the tables so that doctor was wholly dependent on the shifts table and not the hospital table. On a side note I am also not sure why the other user removed the ER tag for this post?

Comment: You're not making sense.  Your shift table relates doctor and patient, it makes no mention of the hospital.  A relation between doctor and patient (or doctor and hospital, for that matter) isn't evident in the 1NF, none of the tables contain their keys together.  In 1NF, you've got Doctor_ID -> (Date, Time) and Patient_ID -> Location.  In 2NF, you've got (Doctor_ID, Patient_ID) -> (Date, Time, Location).  You can't do that with normalization, it doesn't change functional dependencies, it's meant to preserve functional dependencies as you reorganize the tables.

Comment: 'You're not making sense' - well I am trying to make as much sense as possible.I see the shifts table was made up of the incorrect FK. I have now included the Hospital_ID as a FK. I have removed the attributes which as you mentioned I can't just 'move' with normalization. I hope this is starting to make more sense now. Thank you for your reply.